# Google maps calibration api

Tags: api, maps, calibration

We know there is a calibration function in google maps. When you clicked the blue dot on map it will allow you to take photo of surrounding and than calibrates(in new versions it does it via AR).
I want to do it manually via api. Is there any google maps api that satisfies this?